# How does Slack calculate "messages posted"?

Tags: slack

If you navigate to MY_WORKSPACE.slack.com/stats#members you can see "Messages Posted" for each member like this:

[image: Slack member stats]

If you export the data as a CSV, the column is called `chats_sent`.

How is this number calculated? I assume it includes all messages to channels. Does it include direct messages? I assume that reactions (e.g. a "thumbs up") do not count toward this number.

I read through https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218407447-view-analytics-and-usage and https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/220556107-How-to-read-Slack-data-exports but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: This sounds like a great question to ask the Slack team directly. And please post the answer, when you get it :-D

Comment: You could test it by sending a message, clicking thumbs up, etc., and seeing if the number has changed.

Answer (score -1):

Stat includes messages from public and private channels as well as DMs. Reactions do not count towards this number.

Comment: Is this in the Slack documentation?